# Insert a value into a table where the id matches the id of a given value in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

This is my mysql tables

Table oc_product:

```
product_id    model 

  36547      KTMTGRD1
```

Table oc_url_alias:

```
url_alias_id             query               keyword

956             product_id=36547    0-Hand-Meat-Grinder-LaCuisine
```

I have all my products in oc_products. I need to populate the oc_url_alias with all my products data from a csv file:

```
Model,keyword

KTMTGRD1,0-Hand-Meat-Grinder-LaCuisine
```

So basically I need to take the model# from the csv file and use it to find the product_id in oc_product. Then I'll have to check if it already exist in oc_alias_id and insert a new row with the data if not.

I don't know if this can be done with mysql queries alone or I will need help from php?
This is a one time thing i need to do to move my shop to another shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

Dont complicate things, if it is a one time thing. Just write a small PHP program.
So Basically You need to create a temp table in the Mysql with 2 columns Model and keyword and dump all the records from the csv file to the temp table.

In your PHP Program read from this temp table and run a loop

```
select * from temp_table;
loop through all the records{

  select count(*) from oc_product where model_no = temp_table.model_no;

     if (count==0){

       insert into the new table;

     }     

}
```

Hope this hepls

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of a subquery and the INSERT IGNORE... syntax (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) should work for you here.

So, if the values from the current line in the CSV file are in $model and $keyword, something like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO oc_url_alias (query, keyword)
    SELECT CONCAT('product_id=',product_id), '$keyword' 
    FROM oc_product WHERE oc_product.model 
    LIKE '$model';
```

Note: You'll have to figure out the best way to interpolate the PHP variable, based on which database access method you are using. The safest way would be to use MYSQLi or PDO and prepared statements, but if not that, run mysql_real_escape_string on them. Never trust any data, even your own.

This should get you on the right track, but you'll need to work out the details.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to my first answer. It a slightly time consuming as you will execute many queries. So Alternatively you can read all the records from the oc_product table, then store it in an array. Then inside the temp_table loop, check if model number from the temp table is present in the oc_product table array. If it exists then dont insert, otherwise insert.

```
select * from oc_product;
$array = store product_id and model;

select * from temp_table;
loop through all the records{


  if (!model_no.exists[$array]){

     insert into the new table;

  }     

}
```